# Background & title cannot be resolved or be a field

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I'm following the Android Game Programming for Dummies by: Derek James. It looks outdated too me because in the book it doesn't include the fragment_main. So I just copied the fragment_main and replaced it in the activity_main and deleted the fragment_main (I followed the how to get rid of fragment_main tutorial on this forum).

I'm trying to make the whack a mole game in the book.

Anyways I get two errors when I followed the book and it said I can run the program now but I am unable to do that because of:

> background cannot be resolved or is not a field
>   title cannot be resolved or is not a field

I have everything the same as the book but why do I get these errors, I checked all over Google to find an answer or something similar but I can't find the error, I would really appreciate if someone can help me out. Sorry for writing a whole paragraph but I should let you know what I did.

This is my WhackAMoleView.java

```
 package com.whackamole;

 import android.content.Context;
 import android.graphics.Bitmap;
 import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
 import android.graphics.Canvas;
 import android.os.Handler;
 import android.os.Message;
 import android.util.AttributeSet;
 import android.view.MotionEvent;
 import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
 import android.view.SurfaceView;

  public class WhackAMoleView extends SurfaceView implements
    SurfaceHolder.Callback {

  private Context myContext;
  private SurfaceHolder mySurfaceHolder;
  private Bitmap backgroundImg;
  private int screenW = 1;
  private int screenH = 1;
  private boolean running = false;
  private boolean onTitle = true;
  private WhackAMoleThread thread;

  public WhackAMoleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);

    thread = new WhackAMoleThread(holder, context, new Handler()

    {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message m) {

        }
    });

    setFocusable(true);

 }

 public WhackAMoleThread getThread() {
    return thread;

}

  class WhackAMoleThread extends Thread {

    public WhackAMoleThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, Context context,
            Handler handler) {
        mySurfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
        myContext = context;
        backgroundImg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                context.getResources(), R.drawable.title);

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (running) {
            Canvas c = null;
            try {
                c = mySurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                synchronized (mySurfaceHolder) {
                    draw(c);
                }
            } finally {
                if (c != null) {
                    mySurfaceHolderunlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }
            }

        }
    }

    private void mySurfaceHolderunlockCanvasAndPost(Canvas c) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        try {
            canvas.drawBitmap(backgroundImg, 0, 0, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    boolean doTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        synchronized (mySurfaceHolder) {
            int eventaction = event.getAction();
            int x = (int) event.getX();
            int Y = (int) event.getY();

            switch (eventaction) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if (onTitle) {
                    backgroundImg = BitmapFactory
                            .decodeResource(myContext.getResources(),
                                    R.drawable.background);
                    backgroundImg = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
                            backgroundImg, screenW, screenH, true);
                    onTitle = false;
                }

                break;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void setSurfaceSize(int width, int height) {
        synchronized (mySurfaceHolder) {
            screenW = width;
            screenH = height;
            backgroundImg = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(backgroundImg, width,
                    height, true);
        }
    }

    public void setRunning(boolean b) {
        running = b;
    }
 }

  @Override
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return thread.doTouchEvent(event);

 }

  @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    thread.setSurfaceSize(width, height);
 }

 @Override
 public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    thread.setRunning(true);
    if (thread.getState() == Thread.State.NEW) {
        thread.start();
    }
 }

 @Override
 public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    thread.setRunning(false);
   }
 }
```

This is my MainActivity.java

```
package com.whackamole;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 private WhackAMoleView myWhackAMoleView;

 /**Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags
    (WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.whackamole_layout);
    myWhackAMoleView = (WhackAMoleView)
            findViewById(R.id.mole);
    myWhackAMoleView.setKeepScreenOn(true);

 }
 }
```

This is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.whackamole"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name">       

    <activity
        android:name="com.whackamole.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Check if in the `res/drawable[-XXXX]` folder you have an image named `background`. Then check if in your `strings.xml` file you have an entry named `title` (I guess this is a string).

Comment: Thank you for your help @G.T. I was missing the drawable.. but I still have three warnings. The value of the local variable X is not used. & The value of the local variable Y is not used. & This Handler class should be static or leaks may occur. (com.whackamole.WhackAMoleView.1)

Comment: If some variables are not used you can simply delete them. Some tutorials that you can find on internet contain errors or warnings. You have to correct them by yourself. For the handler, you can follow the tips given by your IDE, make it static.

Comment: Okay so whatever errors I get I`ll just use the tips that will correct it, once again thank you very much!

Answer (score -2):

```
                mySurfaceHolderunlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            }
        }

    }
}

mySurfaceHolderunlockCanvasAndPost should be mySurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost

*private void mySurfaceHolderunlockCanvasAndPost(Canvas c) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}* should not be here
```